# How do I show the same set of sequences spawned parallely in a sequence diagram?

Tags: parallel-processing, uml

Imagine that a program spawns multiple threads to do the same kind of sequences interacting with different versions of objects. How do I model this in a sequence diagram?

Say a thread is being replicated n number of times and this thread then performs some operations with objects A,B and C n number of times. How does one show it in a sequence diagram?

Comment: `different versions of objects` you mean different instances of the same classes ? The  executions are done in parallel very probably ?

Comment: I was not able to edit my content but what I wanted was, say a thread is being replicated n number of times and this thread then performs some operations with objects A,B and C  n number of times. How does one show it in a sequence diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply show the spawning of the sub-processes and nothing else in a first diagram. Then create a 2nd diagram showing the details for what happens in one of the threads. Now you only need some textual description (a note) which links both diagrams. Alternatively you can drop the detail diagram as Interaction Occurence onto the lifelines of the single threads.

[image]

Comment: Did the UML-tool automatically draft and accounts for all the costs-of-overheads burnt in the phases of ***spawning*** threads/processes, parameters & data exchange ***communications***, results ***returning*** and ( finally ) ***termination*** of the threads/processes, or you put all these initial ( for obvious reasons non-incidentally sequential ) overheads during thread spawning **manually**? These runt-time costs are cardinal for the revised, overhead-aware Amdahls Law re-formulation of achievable parallel speedup *( or slowdown )*. Thank you for your insights on this tooling.

Comment: @user3666197 Well, you're talking about details which might or might not be of interest. If so, you have to put in a lot of effort to show those gory details. If not (which is pretty fine for most cases) you can see with the above that certain interactions are running concurrently.

Comment: @user3666197 And: in almost all cases your program will run in parallel threads with and other programs and you will definitely not be interested in showing that in any case. Except you design a scheduling algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for opinions on usefulness. Did I get from comments correctly the UML-tool did not automate ( the less quantitatively account for, in a code-generation postprocessor-phase ) for any such process-orchestration the actual ( on that purpose added ) add-on overheads for further performance validation ( proofs of *(expected)*-**speedup** cardinal constraints )? It sounds to me that not, yet an explicit confirmation of having done the above illustration manual ( or, on the contrary, automated by the UML-tool ) is an ultimate statement. ( Theory https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 )

Comment: @user3666197 The tool does not do anthing automatically. It's a modeling tool and you tell it how the model shall look like.

Comment: Thank you. Understood. UML-tool leaves all these levels of detail on the human side of the Man-Machine-Interface :o) Thank you for your kind sharing the insights.